# onclick focusing to create js textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i converted the flash file to html5 using create js but actionscripts are not working, i want to add values to the textbox ans_txt1 and ans_txt . and text should be focused onclick .. how and whats the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CreateJS export from 
E313ST01MT01_Comparison_Near_farther_activity</title>  
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.6.0.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.3.0.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/soundjs-0.4.0.min.js"></script>    
<script src="../../Copy of wt/E313ST01MT01_Comparison_Near_farther_activity.js"></script>    
<script>    
(function (lib, img, cjs) {    
var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes    
var rect; // used to reference frame bounds    
// stage content:    
(lib.E313ST01MT01_Comparison_Near_farther_activity = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // top-gui

    this.instance = new lib.topguiA();

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]}).wait(164));

    // btns

    this.pre_btn = new lib.pre45();
    this.pre_btn.setTransform(654.5,490.4,0.662,0.662);

    this.pre_btn.shadow = new cjs.Shadow("#000000",0,0,5);

    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.pre_btn, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.pre45(), 3);


    this.next_btn = new lib.next45();

    this.next_btn.setTransform(676.6,461.8,0.662,0.662);
    this.next_btn.shadow = new cjs.Shadow("#000000",0,0,5);

    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.next_btn, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.next45(), 3);


    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.next_btn},
{t:this.pre_btn}]}).wait(164));

    // wrong dis
    this.dis2_mc = new lib.S4555x();
    this.dis2_mc.setTransform(412.4,418.3,0.77,1.001,0,0,0,-28.2,33.5);

    this.dis1_mc = new lib._4985x();

    this.dis1_mc.setTransform(242,319.4,0.77,1.001,0,0,0,-28.2,33.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[]}).to({state:[{t:this.dis1_mc},{t:this.dis2_mc}]},160).wait(4));

    // wrong
    this.wr2_mc = new lib.wrong();

    this.wr2_mc.setTransform(413.2,381.1,2.21,2.214,0,0,0,15.8,11.1);

    this.wr1_mc = new lib.wrong();

    this.wr1_mc.setTransform(243.7,276.9,2.21,2.214,0,0,0,15.8,11.1);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[]}).to({state:[{t:this.wr1_mc},{t:this.wr2_mc}]},160).wait(4));

    // side mc

    this.sd_mc = new lib.gg();

    this.sd_mc.setTransform(875,122);
    this.sd_mc._off = true;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.sd_mc).wait(160).to({_off:false},0).wait(4));

    // ansfields

    this.ans2_txt = new cjs.Text("", "bold 35px TektonPro-Bold", "#FFFFFF");

    this.ans2_txt.textAlign = "center";

    this.ans2_txt.lineHeight = 37;

    this.ans2_txt.lineWidth = 39;

    this.ans2_txt.setTransform(411.1,357.9);


    this.ans1_txt = new cjs.Text("", "bold 35px TektonPro-Bold", "#FFFFFF");

    this.ans1_txt.textAlign = "center";

    this.ans1_txt.lineHeight = 37;

    this.ans1_txt.lineWidth = 36;

    this.ans1_txt.setTransform(241.6,253.7);

    this.ans1_txt.id= 2;

    this.ans1_txt.mouseEnabled="true";

    this.ans1_txt.onclick="focus()"

// Layer 13

    this.an_mc = new lib.welldoneg();

    this.an_mc.setTransform(84.1,361.1,0.763,0.763,0,0,180,305.9,133.4);

    this.an_mc._off = true;


    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.an_mc).wait(40).to({_off:false},0).wait(1));
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you are asking about making editable text, ie Input Text in Adobe Animate.

This is not supported in HTML5 output, or in CreateJS. Input text on a canvas is a much harder thing to do, and would have super-limited support, as Canvas's own text implementation is pretty poor.

You could add your own support using HTML input elements, and the [EaselJS DOMElement class](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DOMElement.html), which lets you add HTML content over top of the stage, but treated like a child of the stage.

If you just want to change the text of the text instance, its pretty easy:

```
exportRoot.ans1_txt.text = "New Text";
```

To do it on click won't work because you don't have an initial text value, so there is nothing on the stage to click.

Hope that helps. You could also look into [ZIMJS](http://zimjs.com/), which runs on CreateJS, and I believe has an editable text control. Not sure how well it plays with Animate though.